# Width of column in columnchart using highcharts

Tags: highcharts, width

Is there a way to control the width of a column in columnchart using highcharts.I feel the width of a single column is very broad and I want a thin column using highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to change that:

- set [pointWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth)
- set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)
- set [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding) and [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding)